# Abusing instance arguments to mimic tactics

Tags: agda

I'm trying to prove some lemmas that are mutually recursive, but unfortunately not structurally recursive, so I have to use `Data.Nat.Induction.Acc`, resulting in half of my code dedicated to explicitly mentioning proofs of facts like `m ≤ m ⊔ n`. Ideally, I'd like to hide these technicalities as much as possible, and upon a quick glance implicit arguments seem promising (and much more lightweight than going full metaprogramming/reflection). But, alas, I'm stuck on that route.

As a model example, consider some mutually recursive trees:

```
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_; refl; subst; sym)

mutual
  data U : Set where
    U-only    : U
    U-with-Vs : (v₁ v₂ : V) → U
  
  data V : Set where
    V-only    : V
    V-with-Us : (u₁ u₂ : U) -> V
```

along with some functions yielding something that's smaller (for the obvious definition of a size), but not structurally smaller:

```
mutual
  iso-U : U → V
  iso-U U-only = V-only
  iso-U (U-with-Vs v₁ v₂) = V-with-Us (iso-V v₁) (iso-V v₂)

  iso-V : V → U
  iso-V V-only = U-only
  iso-V (V-with-Us u₁ u₂) = U-with-Vs (iso-U u₁) (iso-U u₂)
```

Now let's define those obvious size measures and prove that `iso` doesn't change that size:

```
mutual
  size-U : U → ℕ
  size-U U-only = zero
  size-U (U-with-Vs v₁ v₂) = suc (size-V v₁ ⊔ size-V v₂)

  size-V : V → ℕ
  size-V V-only = zero
  size-V (V-with-Us u₁ u₂) = suc (size-U u₁ ⊔ size-U u₂)

mutual
  size-U-iso-V : ∀ v
               → size-U (iso-V v) ≡ size-V v
  size-U-iso-V V-only = refl
  size-U-iso-V (V-with-Us u₁ u₂) rewrite size-V-iso-U u₁ | size-V-iso-U u₂ = refl

  size-V-iso-U : ∀ u
               → size-V (iso-U u) ≡ size-U u
  size-V-iso-U U-only = refl
  size-V-iso-U (U-with-Vs v₁ v₂) rewrite size-U-iso-V v₁ | size-U-iso-V v₂ = refl
```

Finally we get to write a nonsensical and useless function that still models what I need to do in my real code:

```
open import Data.Nat.Induction

module Explicit where
  mutual
    count-U : (u : U) → Acc _<_ (size-U u) → ℕ
    count-U U-only _ = zero
    count-U (U-with-Vs v₁ v₂) (acc rec) =
      let ineq = m≤m⊔n (size-V v₁) (size-V v₂)
          ineq' = subst (_≤ size-V v₁ ⊔ size-V v₂) (sym (size-U-iso-V v₁)) ineq
          r₁ = rec _ (s≤s ineq')
          r₂ = rec _ (s≤s (n≤m⊔n _ _))
       in suc (count-U (iso-V v₁) r₁ + count-V v₂ r₂)

    count-V : (v : V) → Acc _<_ (size-V v) → ℕ
    count-V V-only _ = zero
    count-V (V-with-Us u₁ u₂) (acc rec) =
      let r₁ = rec _ (s≤s (m≤m⊔n _ _))
          r₂ = rec _ (s≤s (n≤m⊔n _ _))
       in suc (count-U u₁ r₁ + count-U u₂ r₂)
```

This typechecks, but all those `r₁`s, `r₂`s and whatever they require in `count-U` are completely irrelevant to the logic of these functions, and I'd like to get rid of them.

Let's give it a shot with instance arguments? Here's my attempt:

```
module Instance where
  instance
    m≤m⊔n' : ∀ {m n} → m ≤ m ⊔ n
    m≤m⊔n' {m} {n} = m≤m⊔n m n

    n≤m⊔n' : ∀ {m n} → n ≤ m ⊔ n
    n≤m⊔n' {m} {n} = n≤m⊔n m n

    acc-rec : ∀ {a z} → ⦃ Acc _<_ z ⦄ → ⦃ a < z ⦄ → Acc _<_ a
    acc-rec ⦃ acc rec ⦄ ⦃ a<z ⦄ = rec _ a<z
  
  mutual
    count-U : (u : U) → ⦃ Acc _<_ (size-U u) ⦄ → ℕ
    count-U U-only = zero
    count-U (U-with-Vs v₁ v₂) = suc ({! !} + count-V v₂)

    count-V : (v : V) → ⦃ Acc _<_ (size-V v) ⦄ → ℕ
    count-V V-only = zero
    count-V (V-with-Us u₁ u₂) = {! !}
```

Agda doesn't like it, though, apparently considering the instance argument to `count-U` as a candidate, and being not sure which one of the two lemmas about `⊔` to use:

```
Failed to solve the following constraints:
  Resolve instance argument
    _124
      : (v₃ v₄ : V) ⦃ z : Acc _<_ (size-U (U-with-Vs v₃ v₄)) ⦄ →
        size-V v₄ < _z_122 (v₁ = v₃) (v₂ = v₄)
  Candidates
    λ {m} {n} → m≤m⊔n m n : ({m n : ℕ} → m ≤ m ⊔ n)
    λ {m} {n} → n≤m⊔n m n : ({m n : ℕ} → n ≤ m ⊔ n)
  Resolve instance argument
    _123
      : (v₃ v₄ : V) ⦃ z : Acc _<_ (size-U (U-with-Vs v₃ v₄)) ⦄ →
        Acc _<_ (_z_122 (v₁ = v₃) (v₂ = v₄))
  Candidates
    _ : Acc _<_ (size-U (U-with-Vs v₁ v₂))
    acc-rec : ({a z : ℕ} ⦃ _ : Acc _<_ z ⦄ ⦃ _ : a < z ⦄ → Acc _<_ a)
```

And even if I leave just a single top-level instance of presumably the right shape

```
    acc-rec : ∀ {m n} → ⦃ Acc _<_ (suc (m ⊔ n)) ⦄ → Acc _<_ n
    acc-rec ⦃ acc rec ⦄ = rec _ (s≤s (n≤m⊔n _ _))
```

Agda would still complain.

I've re-read the section on instance resolution in Agda docs a few times, but I'm still not sure why it behaves this way.

What am I doing wrong? Can I achieve what I want with instance arguments? Or shall I just go and learn Agda metaprogramming?

Comment: Couldn't you sidestep this whole issue by making `U` and `V` into [sized types](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2/language/sized-types.html)?